# call second dispatch after state was update

Tags: redux, state

I wrote a phone book app to learn redux with two main states: the phone book, and the phone book in edit mode. So when the user finishes editing, I'm validating the values on the edited object and update the original one.

I have a problem that I need to send the approve dispatch function after the state has been updated with the new user input. I tried to create another function in mapDispatchtoProps and call it from ownProps.func() but it seems it doesn't recognize it. And if I put the verification inside the approve edit function it not using the updated state.

So I end up writing something like that:

```
const isEditApprove = (dispach, ownProps) => {
  let EditApprove = true;
  if (!ownProps.phone || ownProps.phone.length > 12 || ownProps.phone.length < 9) {
    dispach(rejectEdit(ownProps.id, 'phone')); // change it to const
    EditApprove = false;
  }
  if (!ownProps.name || ownProps.name.trim().indexOf(' ') === -1) {
    dispach(rejectEdit(ownProps.id, 'name')); // change it to const
    EditApprove = false;
  }
  return EditApprove;
};

const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
const mapDispatchtoProps = (dispach, ownProps) => ({
addUserHandler() {
    if (isEditApprove(dispach, ownProps)) {
      dispach(toggleAddUserMode(ownProps.addUserMode));
    }
  },

editUserHandler(event) {
    dispach(changeUserInfo(ownProps.id, event.target.name, event.target.value));

  },
approveEditHandler() {
    if (isEditApprove(dispach, ownProps)) {
      dispach(approveEdit(ownProps.id, ownProps.phone, ownProps.name));
      dispach(toggleEditMode(ownProps.id, ownProps.name, ownProps.phone, ownProps.editMode));
    }
  },
```

It's working but I feel like there is a better way to do it then my isEditApprove func. Do I need to use async middleware (even though I'm not call to any server)?

Thanks,
Or

Edit:

Added my actions:

```
export function toggleEditMode(id, name, phone, editMode) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_EDIT_MODE,
    payload: {
      name,
      phone,
      id,
      editMode: !editMode,
    },
  };
}

export function approveEdit(id, phone, name) {
  return { type: APPROVE_EDIT, payload: { id, phone, name } };
}

export function rejectEdit(id, errorType) {
  let errorMessage;
  switch (errorType) {
    case 'phone':
      errorMessage = 'The phone number must be between';
      break;
    case 'name':
      errorMessage = 'TThe name must contain two words';
      break;
    default:
      errorMessage = 'Unknown error';
  }
  return { type: REJECT_EDIT, payload: { id, errorType, errorMessage } };
}
```

Comment: Can you show your actions?

Comment: @TheReason sure, added them